# How many MSDN accounts per MSDN subscription?

Tags: subscription

We recently bought a handful of MSDN subscriptions.  Should we have received one MSDN account per subscription?  Or must all of our subscriptions be managed through a single account?

(In case you're curious about why we can't just examine whatever we received from Microsoft, the problem is that engineering and IT have a very antagonistic relationship around here.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whoever bought the subscription should have been given a master entitlement. They then go and associate their live account with that entitlement. From there they provision subscriptions to individuals to use via their own live id.